# Anywhere Administration application with the Chrome Simulator

Tags: maximo-anywhere

I am trying to setup the Anywhere Administration application in Maximo. I have altered `worklight.properties` with `si.adminmode=true` in the MobileFirst Studio and done a buikld all. I have also run `Anywhere-Admin-Loader` allApps.

I can see my apps and their lookUp data resources but when I put a query against the resource in the admin app the simulator does not honor it an returns data based on the clause in the app.xml.

What step have a missed in the Studio?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are using a standalone mobilefirst server after making the change in worklight.properties, you have to rebuild and redeploy the runtime war to the standalone server and restart the standalone server.

If you using the embedded server of MobileFirst Studio to run the runtime, as long as you have "Build Automatically" set at the project level it should be rebuilding and redeploying the war automatically to pickup the si.adminmode=true change.  You might have to restart the server from within Studio to get these changes to be picked up.

From the application itself, you have to logout and log back in to pickup these administrative changes.

Comment: I noticed that the Build from eclipse was only building the apps and not the war file. I tried the build.cmd but that complained about windows8 native folder being missing so I ended up modifying the war file manually to alter the properties

Comment: The other thing I noticed is the Query Definition dialog in the Object Structure app and the OSLC Resources app does not really work. It keeps throwing relationship not found and null pointer errors.

This is required to get the queries setup correctly when using the Admin App else only the owner of the Query is allowed to use the query.

I manually fixed the OSLCQuery table and marked my queries as public.

There is a lot of manual messing around as things don't seem to gel in properly